# Elasticsearch client API

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-client

my question is about different Elasticsearch client APIs .. I wanted to migrate form Elasticsearch 6.2 to Elasticsearch 7

- Currently i am using JEST Client library with elasticsearch v6.2, but its absolute now therefore with the upgrade i wanted to used client library provided by Elasticsearch, but number of libraries provided by Elasticsearch make me lost which one to use with v7.15

these are following ES client libraries

- Java client :

  - deprecated in 7.9
    https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/7.9/java-docs-index.html
- REST clients: there are two REST clients

  - Low level REST client.

    - request marshalling and response un-marshalling is handled by the client
      itself.

      - internally uses "Apache Http Async Client"
      - provide some basic domentation of rintailizing, request/response with java code
  - High Level client

    - deprecated in 7.15
    - it a layer on top of Low level client
    - performs request marshalling and response un-marshalling is handled by the client         itself.
    - provides documentation with Java code
      https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/7.15/java-rest-high-document-index.html

so its look like Elasticsearch 7.15 can only use  **"Low level REST client"** because other two clients " Java client " and  **"RES High Level clien"** are deprecated.
and using REST LOW level client require to write lots of basic codes like marschalling /un-marshalling  etc

is my understating correct ?
is there any other Elasticsearch client available /better to use to migrate to 7.15 ?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, this is the only way for this version.

But starting with 7.16 version there is a new client ⇾ **ElasticsearchClient** handling marshalling and unmarshalling by itself (You pass class type as a parameter with calls) with already pretty neet documentation existing:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/master/connecting.html